# Ansible regular expression to match a string from a list of line

Tags: ansible-playbook

I'm trying to read a content of file from remote file. but i want the message to be displayed only matched UUID from fstab file. but when i ran below playbook it is throwing below error.

playbook:

```
- name: read content from a file
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: read a content
      slurp:
        src: /etc/fstab
      register: output
    - name: print
      debug:
       msg: "{{ (output['content'] | b64decode).split('\n') | regex_search('^\\S+/UUID\b.*', multiline=True) }}"
```

error:

```
TASK [print] *************************************************************************************************************
FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (output['content'] | b64decode).split('\n') | regex_search('^\\\\S+/UUID\b.*', multiline=True) }}): expected string or bytes-like object"}
```

Comment: I want to fetch the specific entry for the nfs share. for eg: 10.10.0.10:/nfsshareid /var/test  nfs      defaults    0       0 ------------> from here i want to grep  with nfsshareid.

Comment: getting the o/p like below when i'm trying to fetch with nfsshareid--------------- "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f4fbd87d9e8>"

Answer (score 1):

First, when I run your playbook I don't get an error; I just get no output from the `debug` task:

```
"msg": ""
```

If you're looking for a list of lines that start with `UUID`, you could do this:

```yaml
- name: read content from a file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: read a content
      slurp:
        src: /etc/fstab
      register: output
    - name: print
      debug:
       msg: >
         {{
           (output['content'] | b64decode).splitlines() |
           select("match", "UUID")
         }}
```

On my system, this produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "UUID=2fbad834-42b2-48fd-868d-3eea12e144de /                       btrfs   subvol=root00,compress=zstd:1 0 0",
        "UUID=c72e509c-453a-4e62-8cea-23ad112765d3 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2",
        "UUID=F3B3-4F58          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2",
        "UUID=2fbad834-42b2-48fd-868d-3eea12e144de /home                   btrfs   subvol=home00,compress=zstd:1 0 0",
    ]
}
```

If you wanted a line matching a *specific* uuid, you could do this:

```yaml
- name: read content from a file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: read a content
      slurp:
        src: /etc/fstab
      register: output
    - name: print
      debug:
       msg: >
         {{
           (output['content'] | b64decode).splitlines() |
           select("match", "UUID=c72e509c-453a-4e62-8cea-23ad112765d3") |
           first
         }}
```

On my system this produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "UUID=c72e509c-453a-4e62-8cea-23ad112765d3 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2\n"
}
```